# YouTube API Create Channel, callback to web app when done?

Tags: youtube-api

Google YouTube API Create Channel https://developers.google.com/youtube/create-channel

Step 4) Your application monitors the WebView to determine when its location changes to the following URL, which indicates that the user's Google Account has been linked to a YouTube channel.

How would I monitor this with Javascript or Angular? Is there any callback I can do to close that window, return to my web application and refresh the page? Thanks.